# Run a method with a Timer

Tags: java, android, methods, timer, timertask

I have a void method which contains some findViewById's and I want to run it every second. How can I do that?
All I've came up with is this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
       Method();
    }
  }, 1000, 1000);
}

public void Method() {
  findViewById(R.id.textView1).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("A second has passed!");
}
```

Comment: Have you created this somewhere  Timer timer = new Timer(); ? in the class

Comment: Yes, the timer is already created.

Comment: it's always nice to post whole code instead parts because nobody will know what is  `findViewById()` and other thing just by looking

Comment: The accepted answer refers to "doing it the Android way." I, for one, had no idea this was an android question; you probably should have mentioned that and/or tagged the question accordingly...

Comment: @dcsohl  When you see the `onCreate` method in the OP question, you must notice that it is Android question.

Comment: @ChakerMallek That's only obvious **to an android developer**. If you're not an android developer, it just sounds like a method name no different from any other. And there are lots of other frameworks out there with similar syntaxes.

Answer (score 0):

Insert your business logic into the run method. That will be called.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
      findViewById(R.id.textView1).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("A second has passed!");
    }
  }, 1000, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Application crashes as soon as it starts.